# splitting text using Pattern.compile

Tags: regex, metacharacters

Here is the line of text:

`003  STATE BANK OF BIK & JAI  A/C.1                 2       1,01,500.00      1          3,160.00         98,340.00+`

Here is my code snippet to split it:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[ ]");
String strs[] = pat.split(s);
for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Next Token = " + strs[i]);
}
```

Here is what I get:

`003,STATE,BANK,OF,BIK,*,JAI...etc.`

What I really want is:

`003,STATE BANK OF BIK & JAI,A/C.1,2.1,01,500.00...etc`

Which pattern or metacharacter do I use to accomplish this?

Comment: its the `STATE BANK OF BIK & JAI` part that will make it difficult, you'll need to find some commonality as this string could be anything, right. maybe give a few other string examples.

Comment: First split the string by A/C, then you get the left which only has number + bankname and right which can be split into the sequence of numbers the way you did it.

Comment: Splitting by a space is going to troublesome. Do all lines have a `A/C`?

Comment: @ashokdesai: You need to provide some explanation about desired logic of splitting. In your string split by space or comma are not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

For your case this split call will work:

```
String data = "003 STATE BANK OF BIK & JAI A/C.1 2 1,01,500.00 1 3,160.00 98,340.00+";
String[] arr = data.split(" +(?=\\S*\\d)|(?<![A-Z&]) +");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
[003, STATE BANK OF BIK & JAI, A/C.1, 2, 1,01,500.00, 1, 3,160.00, 98,340.00+]
```